# Bad file descriptor when running bash commands asynchronously with go-task

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

so first off, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there are bugs that need to be worked out in the `go-task` project on GitHub.

I'm running into issues where occasionally I run into an error that looks something like this:

```
context canceled
task: Failed to run task "start": task: Failed to run task "upstream:common": task: Failed to run task "upstream:common:merge:variables": task: Failed to run task "upstream:common:merge:variables:subtype": fork/exec /usr/bin/jq: bad file descriptor
```

Some sample code that causes this issue is:

```
function mergePackages() {
  # Merge the files
  TMP="$(mktemp)"
  jq --arg keywords "$(jq '.keywords[]' "$1" "$2" | jq -s '. | unique')" -s -S '.[0] * .[1] | .keywords = ($keywords | fromjson) | .' "$1" "$2" > "$TMP"
  mv "$TMP" "$3"
}

for FOLDER in project-*/; do
  SUBTYPE="$(echo "$FOLDER" | sed 's/project-\(.*\)\//\1/')"
  mergePackages "./.common/package.hbs.json" "project-$SUBTYPE/package.hbs.json" "./.common-$SUBTYPE/package.hbs.json" &
done
wait
```

The issue seems to occur most often when I'm adding `&` to the end of a bash command for an inline function to execute although I have seem it happen even if a function is called without `&`.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: a `local TMP="$(mktemp)"` could help

Comment: It has nothing to do with the problem at hand but I would replace `SUBTYPE="$(echo "$FOLDER" | sed 's/project-\(.*\)\//\1/')"` with `SUBTYPE="${FOLDER#*-}"`. see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Comment: You haven't provided any context about what `go-task` is, or how it is related to this bash code. How many project directories are there?